# FIXED: HTML format paragraph so its pleasing to the eye

Tags: html, containers

I have a html code where I want to store long paragrapsh of information. The only issue is that in my code I don't want hundreds of sentences on just one line. Id rather see it formatted like:

```
 <div id ="sidebar">
            <div><b> Things to take into account: </b></div>
            <div>
            <p>
            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            </p>
            </div>

        </div>
```

However, when I do it this way and run my website the words run outside the container they are in

Can you help give me a way to display it this way in the code while keeping the words inside it's container?

[image]

my css:

```
#sidebar {

    "background-color: #eee;
    height: 200px;
    width:350px;
    float:left;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: block;
    }
```

UPDATE: changed X to words and fixed it. Weird but ok lol

[image]

Comment: What sort of styling do you have on the text container. It may be you want to change the sizing or overflow properties.

Comment: Word-wrap? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp

Comment: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX is not a word. Show a *real* example and specify how the text should be formatted (divided into lines).

Comment: oh wow... so because they are not words it causes it. Did not know that. XD

Comment: I was simply putting "x" as a filler. I will make sure to not do that from now on. Thanks for the help. I'm not sure if giving you a point shows the question was answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that xxxxxxxxxxxxxx is considered one word and by default the browser won't break this word.

adding

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

Will fix this, but I would guess once you use actual text in there it will break more naturally since it won't be a single word of so many characters.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ktbypbtt/

Here is another fiddle without the word-wrap, but with actual text.
http://jsfiddle.net/ktbypbtt/1/

Notice how it breaks itself since the browser will naturally wrap the word after each word if it hits the end of the div, but needs to be specifically told to break words.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `<br>` tag where ever you want the text to go to the next line

```
 <div id ="sidebar">
            <div><b> Things to take into ACCOUNT: </b></div>
            <div>
            <p>
            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX<br>
            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX<br>
            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX<br>
            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX<br>
            </p>
            </div>

        </div>
```

*Helpful? Let me know :)*

Comment: The <br> doesn't work. Also wouldn't that cause a actual break on the page? I just want the words to automatically word wrap but have it more appealing inside my code

Comment: @AlyssaCooke did you try?

Comment: I tried it as you can see in my above comment. The issue was that they were all X instead of words so break didn't catch it so it seemed. I fixed my code when I made the X all words (without <br>). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

add some css.

```
#sidebar{
  display: block;
}
```

or add a class to your wrapping div and do the same thing with setting display as block

**edited**
You could cut off the overflow:

```
#sidebar{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5deyo1tb/

Comment: the display command didn't do anything. I think its how I am showing it in my code that is causing the issue. Not sure why